# Create a bash function that can store in a new document all the files with a given extension

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I've just started to use linux and bash. I wanted to know how to create a bash function that can add all the files that end with .conf that any user could read into a file. And for the files that a normal user cannot read to be added into another file.
Im running it like this, but im getting  this error code 4: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")
'''

```
add_files () {
    readable_file_list=()
    unreadable_file_list=()

    # Find all files with .conf extension
    for file in /*.conf; do
        # Check if file is readable by any user
        if [[ -r "$file" ]]; then
            # Add file to readable list
            readable_file_list+=("$file")
        else
            # Add file to unreadable list
            unreadable_file_list+=("$file")
        fi
    done

    # Add readable files to readable_files.txt
    printf '%s\n' "${readable_file_list[@]}" > readable_files.txt

    # Add unreadable files to unreadable_files.txt
    printf '%s\n' "${unreadable_file_list[@]}" > unreadable_files.txt
}
```

'''

Any ideas on why?

Comment: Use the `find` command with `-name` to match the filename and `-perm` to test permissions.

Comment: The most likely cause of the problem is that you are trying to run the code with `sh` instead of `bash`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between sh and Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: Note that `[[ -r $file ]]` only tests if the file is readable by the *current* user.  A file can be readable by the current user but not by other users.  Note also that readability of a file by users also depends on readability of directories on the file's path in the file system.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function:

```
function add_files {
    readable_file_list=()
    unreadable_file_list=()

    # Find all files with .conf extension
    for file in /path/to/directory/*.conf; do
        # Check if file is readable by any user
        if [[ -r "$file" ]]; then
            # Add file to readable list
            readable_file_list+=("$file")
        else
            # Add file to unreadable list
            unreadable_file_list+=("$file")
        fi
    done

    # Add readable files to readable_files.txt
    printf '%s\n' "${readable_file_list[@]}" > readable_files.txt

    # Add unreadable files to unreadable_files.txt
    printf '%s\n' "${unreadable_file_list[@]}" > unreadable_files.txt
}
```

Comment: I keep running it and getting this error 4: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}"). Do you know why?